# Why is $y= 0$ not a solution of this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> The solution of the differential equation $(x^2 y^2 -1)dy + 2xy^3 dx= 0$ is:
>
> a) $1+x^2y^2 = cx$
>
> b) $1+x^2 y^2 = cy$
>
> c) $y=0$
>
> d) $y = -\dfrac{1}{x^2}$

By converting the equation into exact differential form and integrating I got option b as the answer and it's correct.

But  I would like to know why option $c$ is not a valid solution.

If we rearrange the differential equation we get:

$\dfrac {dy}{dx}= \dfrac{2xy^3}{1- x^2 y^2}$

$\implies y' = 0$ for $y = 0$

Also, originally too for $y=0 $ the slope $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= 0$.

Then why is $y = 0$ not a solution?

Answer given is only option $b$.

Comment: What makes you believe that $y=0$ is *not* a solution?  What is the complete statement of the original problem?  (Are you sure that it doesn't ask for nontrivial solutions?)

Comment: @XanderHenderson Answer given is only option b which is why I thought y=0 is not a solution. I have posted the complete statement of the problem as it is given in my book.

Comment: `Answer given is only option b.`  By whom?  What is the source of this problem?  If you are taking a class, I would suggest that this is a question better posed to an instructor.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Please see my edited comment.

Comment: Your edited comment does not address my question... What is the source of this problem?  Which book does it come from?  It appears to me that the question is somewhat ill-posed, but perhaps the author of the text has previously defined a solution to a DE to be a non-trivial solution.  Perhaps it is just a typo.  Have you tried looking for errata on the text?  While I appreciate the effort you put into explaining your thoughts on the problem, the question is still deeply lacking in necessary context...

Answer (score 3):

You can view the solution $y = 0$ as a limit of the more general solution in *(b)*.  Specifically, one of the possible solutions is
$$
1 - c y + x^2 y^2 = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad y = \frac{c - \sqrt{c^2 - 4 x^2}}{2 x^2} 
$$
But in the limit $c \to \infty$, and for any value of $x$, we have 
$$
\lim_{c \to \infty} \left[c - \sqrt{c^2 - 4 x^2} \right] = \lim_{c \to \infty} \left[\frac{4 x^2}{c + \sqrt{c^2 - 4 x^2}} \right] = 0
$$
and so $y \to 0$ for all values of $x$.  Thus, the solution $y = 0$ can be viewed as a special case of the more general solution $cy = 1 + x^2 y^2$ in the limit $c \to \infty$.

Comment: But there is no value of $c$ such that $1=0$ (which is what you get if $1-x^2y^2 = cy$ with $y=0$).  So, while the trivial solution can be seen as the *limit* of a family of solutions of the kind described, it is not a *special case* of such a solution.

Comment: A better form for a general solution would be $c(1+x^2y^2)=y$, which includes the trivial solution, while in the original form $c=0$ does not result in a solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you rearrange the differential equation, you're implicitly assuming that $y'$ is not $0$ for all $x$. So the only solutions obtained by rearranging are the ones where $y'$ does not vanish throughout.

Comment: @ Sudheesh Surendranath, I think when you rearrange the equation, you should assume that $x^2y^2−1$ is not zero and not that $y'$ is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a solution, the trivial solution. But in most cases it is not of interest.

Answer (score 1):

You would usually only give the trivial solution if it were the only solution. In this case there is a non-trivial solution so you give that.